# Two Option ID 51 in DHCP

Tags: dhcp, netsh

I'm using this command:

```
netsh dhcp server \\serverName 10.11.12.3 show optionvalue
```

and am getting back two values for option 51:

```
Changed the current scope context to 10.11.12.3 scope.
Options for Scope 10.11.12.3:
For user class [Default BOOTP Class]:
OptionId : 51
Option Value:
Number of Option Elements = 1
Option Element Type = DWORD
Option Element Value = 691200
DHCP Standard Option :
OptionId : 51
Option Value:
Number of Option Elements = 1
Option Element Type = DWORD
Option Element Value = 14400
...
```

The one shown in the GUI 4hrs (14400).

Why is there a second value of 691200?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to admit that I've never looked specifically at option 51 before but your question intrigued me so I did some testing. I think the answer is that you have BOOTP enabled with a lease duration that's different for BOOTP clients than the lease duration for DHCP clients.

Here are some screenshots illustrating this:

[image]

[image]

[image]